# How to make underline shorter?

Tags: symbols

How to make the length of underline shorter in latex ?

For example in this environment :

$\underline{\mathcal{G}}$

Thank you,

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `${\mspace{2mu}\underline{\mspace{-2mu}\mathcal{G}\mspace{-2mu}}\mspace{2mu}}$` is long to write, but is what you want. Happily, you can bury this in a macro. Note: `\mspace` requires `amsmath`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{book}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{fourier}
    \newcommand\varul[2][3]{\mkern#1mu\underline{\mkern-#1mu#2\mkern-#1mu}\mkern#1mu}

    \begin{document}

     \[a\underline{\mathcal G} a \]%
     \[a\varul{\mathcal G}a \]%

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just to be able to use it in text mode without having to enter $ … $. Actually, I had a problem on testing an initial version with a missing `$` (indeed a missing paired `}`) and I forgot to remove it.